# external URL with API endpoint in SpringBoot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, api, endpoint

I was recently asked to transform a list of data and submit it to an API endpoint. I know how to do this except the endpoint is on an external URL and I can’t get it to work. Does anyone know how to do this in SpringBoot?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Spring Boot itself has no way of calling an external HTTP API. You can use other libraries like [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Comment: @zingcodes63, what about RestTemplate and Webclient ?